# Moving node on drag setOnMouseDragged fires only on parent

Tags: java, javafx

I have a node that I want to move on drag, when I use setOnMouseClicked it fires even if it is clicked on the children of the node, but setOnMouseDragged fires only if the drag is on the parent:

```
    node.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("offset");

    });
    node.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        System.out.println("move");
    });
```

I want to fire the drag event even if it is done on a child of the node. Why mouseClicked and mouseDragged have different behavior?

Comment: You deleted your other questions, but if you want to see a small demo of using `ListView` for chat take a look at https://gist.github.com/tkslaw/518f95d10a8e6505525fb9c4c409a255

Comment: @Slaw Oh, thanks I thought the discussion was over. Is it better to delete unanswered questions, tho? Last question also went to a different direction.

Comment: @Slaw I also undeleted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967600/appending-older-content-on-scroll-javafx?noredirect=1 If you want to post the example there

Comment: @Slaw Hey I tried it with custom factory, but I have one problem. When the cells are different height because of the text the scrolling is buggy, it skips from one place to another also the scroll bar's thumb is getting bigger in one place and when the cell is bigger it is getting smaller. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: @Slaw it is also happening if I just add several cells with lets say 200 height and after that I add several with 50 height.

Comment: I believe this is happening because the virtual flow makes a best guess as to how much space is "above" and "below" the current view. This is accurate when the cells have a fixed height or are all roughly the same height but apparently a little buggy when the cells are of significantly different heights. I don't know if there's anything you can do about this—outside of implementing a list-view-like control yourself (very much non-trivial).

Comment: I'm actually a little disappointed in this behavior. There appears to be a decent number of bugs reported related to this, some claiming to be "fixed", others unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like below:

```
parent.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if(e.isStillSincePress()){
        //executed when not from drag
    }
});
```

MouseEvent::isStillSincePress checks to see if press and released was in the same node.

[MouseEvent::MOUSE_CLICKED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_CLICKED)

> This event occurs when mouse button has been clicked (pressed and released on the same node). This event provides a button-like behavior to any node. Note that even long drags can generate click event (it is delivered to the top-most node on which the mouse was both pressed and released).

to block an event from reaching a parent you can also use [Event::consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume())

----------EDIT----------

added sample code for drag

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragApplication extends Application{

    private double startX = 0, startY = 0;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        EventHandler< MouseEvent> clicked = e -> System.out.printf( "%s clicked%n", e.getTarget());

        EventHandler< MouseEvent> pressed = e -> {
            startX = e.getX();
            startY = e.getY();
        };

        EventHandler< MouseEvent> dragged = e -> {
            Node n = (Node) e.getTarget();
            //in case of button it returns the Text node not the button
            if(n instanceof Text)
                n = n.getParent();
            n.layoutXProperty().set( n.getLayoutX() + e.getX() - startX);
            n.layoutYProperty().set( n.getLayoutY() + e.getY() - startY);
        };

        Button paneButton = new Button( "Pane Button");
        paneButton.setOnAction( a -> System.out.println( "Pane Button Action"));
        paneButton.setOnMouseClicked( clicked);
        paneButton.setOnMousePressed( pressed);
        paneButton.setOnMouseDragged( dragged);

        Pane pane = new Pane( paneButton);
        pane.setLayoutX( 200);
        pane.setOnMouseClicked( clicked);
        pane.setOnMousePressed( pressed);
        pane.setOnMouseDragged( dragged);
        pane.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: GREEN; -fx-min-width:200; -fx-min-height:200;");

        Button achoreButton = new Button( "Anchor Button");
        achoreButton.setOnAction( a -> System.out.println( "Anchor Button Action"));
        achoreButton.setOnMouseClicked( clicked);
        achoreButton.setOnMousePressed( pressed);
        achoreButton.setOnMouseDragged( dragged);

        Button transparentAchoreButton = new Button( "Transparent Anchor Button");
        transparentAchoreButton.setMouseTransparent( true);
        transparentAchoreButton.setOnAction( a -> System.out.println( "Anchor Button Action"));
        transparentAchoreButton.setOnMouseClicked( clicked);
        transparentAchoreButton.setOnMousePressed( pressed);
        transparentAchoreButton.setOnMouseDragged( dragged);

        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane(achoreButton, transparentAchoreButton);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor( achoreButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor( achoreButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor( transparentAchoreButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor( transparentAchoreButton, 10.0);
        anchor.setOnMouseClicked( clicked);
        anchor.setOnMousePressed( pressed);
        anchor.setOnMouseDragged( dragged);
        anchor.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: RED; -fx-min-width:200; -fx-min-height:200;");

        Pane root = new Pane(  anchor,pane);

        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle( "Text scaling problem");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args){
        launch( args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but then I tried it and I realized that this is not what I meant. I don't mean I want to trigger the click when its not from a drag, but I want the drag to be executed if it is done on a child. onMouseClick and Pressed both execute even if they are done on the parent I guess it's called top most node, but drag is only done on the node itself, if I drag on the child nothing happens, but when I am using onMouseClicked, even clicking on the child is triggering the method.

Comment: But if I use event handler with mouse drag it is working, even if I drag on any of the children. I want the same behavior as doing it with a handler.

Comment: is there anyway you can show your code? i am not sure what you mean. i wrote a sample drag of a button on top of a pane and i can drag both the button and pane with no issues. if dragging is issue let me know and i will post my example.

Comment: yes dragging is the issue lets say that that parent is an anchor pane and it has a child with anchor points 0 0 0 0 so it takes all the width and height of the parent when I attach the event to the parent it doesn't work because the child takes the full width and height of the parent and I am dragging on the child

Comment: added the sample code with achor, let me know if this helps.

Comment: added 2 buttons to anchor one is will not receive mouse events.

Comment: "_there is no easy way of stop it from reaching the parent_"—that's what `Event.consume()` is for.

Comment: @Slaw thanks, updated the answer. i don't know how i forgot about consume.